# Custom Navigation build using wp_nav_menu and walker

Tags: theme-development, customization, menus, walker

**What I have**

Right now I have an old template in plain HTML. In there I use a custom Navigation menu built like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-menu main-menu-1" id="main-menu">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active dropdown">
         <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Parent item 1</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-menu-separator"></li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">Parent item 2</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**What I need**

Right now I need to output my Wordpress Navigation just like this. Including every `class` and `data-toggle` element and all the `main-menu-seperator li` elements.

I know, that I need to use a custom walker for this. But I really don't know how to start with this.

**The problem**

I never used custom walkers extending the `Walker_Nav_Menu` before. So if anyone can help me building my custom navigation, I really would appreciate it!

The next problem is, that I don't know how to set the `class="active"` on the `li` elements of the parent and the childs.

**Thank you very much in advance!**

**UPDATE 1**

I just tried things with my custom walker and I'm getting some results now.

What I need right now:

- I only want to add the `class` "dropdown" to the parent `li` element, if the element has children.
- I still need a way to add my separator `li`'s after each menu element.
- Still missing is the possibility to show an "active" state. I saw, that `wp_nav_menu` is already outputting some `classes` like "`current-page-item`" and "`current-menu-item`"

This is what my `wp_nav_menu` command looks like:

```
$defaults = array(
'theme_location'  => '',
'menu'            => '',
'container'       => 'div',
'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse main-menu main-menu-1',
'container_id'    => 'main-menu',
'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
'menu_id'         => '',
'echo'            => true,
'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
'before'          => '',
'after'           => '',
'link_before'     => '',
'link_after'      => '',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
'depth'           => 2,
'walker'          => new FoxTransport_Walker()
);
wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

And this is how my walker looks right now:

```
class FoxTransport_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

// add classes to ul sub-menus
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array(
        'dropdown-menu'
        );
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '" role="menu">' . "\n";
}

// add main/sub classes to li's and links
 function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

    // depth dependent classes
    $depth_classes = array(
        ( $depth == 0 ? 'dropdown' : '' )
    );
    $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

    // passed classes
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

    // build html
    $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

    // link attributes
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ' data-toggle="dropdown"';

    $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
        $args->before,
        $attributes,
        $args->link_before,
        apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
        $args->link_after,
        $args->after
    );

    // build html
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
   }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I just solved one problem. I have my active class now. The solution for me now was to add some few line in jQuery where I get the wordpress classes and add my ones then like this:

```
$('.current-page-item').addClass('active');
$('.current-menu-item').addClass('active');
$('.current_page_parent').addClass('active');
$('.menu-item-has-children').addClass('dropdown');
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').attr('data-toggle','dropdown');
```

**That means that the following questions still remain:**

- I don't know how to add my separator `li`'s after each parent menu item expect the last one.